# CSS display:none firing before click event on link, so click is taken as a click on body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am transforming a medium sized CMS site (400 pages) to a responsive, mobile friendly, mobile first web site.

Being a site for Mexican customers where 2g is the norm and 3g exceptional, the site needs to be streamlined to the smallest possible page size for a reasonable page load speed.

This prevent the usage of, fair to say convenient but "bloated" JS libraries (JQuery, etc), web page frameworks as Bootstrap, Foundation, and CMS's as WordPress, Joomla, etc.

So far the lightweight CMS, is no problem, Presentation will be carried with light framework "Kube".

The only problem left is that I could not find any pure CSS multilevel dropdown menu, which can be switched from vertical on mobiles to horizontal in larger screens. Almost a 100 checked. Adding JQuery and/or Bootstrap just for the menu, de-merits all other gains.

So far, I have coded a pure CSS lightweight menu script, which is clean,  light and easy to build from DB, which works "almost perfectly" on mobiles and that could be easily transformed to an horizontal desktop menu with the proper media query dependant CSS. (Code below).

```css
/* Basic Styles */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: #333333;
  font: 0.75em/1.5em Arial, sans-serif;
}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 96%;
}
/* responsive rules */
@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  /* Basic positions & colors schema */
  ul {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  div,
  ul {
    background-color: #322b8c;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #68e2f0;
    border-width: 2px;
  }
  a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  hover {
    background-color: #655ccd;
    color: #bf353d;
  }
  active {
    background-color: #655ccd;
    color: #bf353d;
  }
  /* Parece que es muy fugaz para devices... */
  /* Browser events response */
  /* Menu Level 1 */
  [class="MENU1"] > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  [class="MENU1"]:hover > ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

  <div class='MENU1'><a href="#">  MENU </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-1</a>
      </li>

      <div class='MENU1'>
        <li><a href="#">  MENU 1-2 >> </a>
        </li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-2-1</a>
          </li>

          <div class='MENU1'>
            <li><a href="#">  MENU 1-2-2 >> </a>
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-2-2-1</a>
              </li>
              <div class='MENU1'>
                <li><a href="#">  MENU 1-2-2 >> </a>
                </li>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-2-2-1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-2 -2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-2-3 </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-2-3 </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-3 </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-3 </a></li>
      <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-4 </a></li>
      <div class='MENU1'>
        <li><a href="#">  MENU 1-5 >> </a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-5-1</a>
          </li>
          <div class='MENU1'>
            <li><a href="#">  MENU 1-5-2 >> </a>
            </li>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU  1-2-5-1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-5-2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-2-5-3 </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-5-3 </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li><a href="wp.html"> MENU 1-6 </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="wp.html" onclick="myFunction();"> MENU 1-7</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The slim code speed beats by a large factor the library, framework, plugin solutions.

The only problem left is:

That being a multilevel menu, the menu, naturally grows vertically as inner sub menus are opened.

Links on those sub menus opened from the top work well.

But: If a link from a lower rank menu branch which is naturally presented after all children from the previous branch of the same rank is currently positioned below the original "Main menu branchs only" menu size, clicking on that link, would not redirect the browser to the linked page, but will consider the click event as a click on whatever was below the link before the menu was opened.

The only explanation I could think of, is that the "unhover": CSS `display:none` is being fired before the click event on the link.

I have searched for  a day on possible solutions and tried many...

I tried to delay the "Display: none"  with CSS by including it within Delay-Properties  along with opacity which is "Transitionable", or after it. Any permutation possible.

I tried adding "on click event" for the link, and even added a standard input element inside the `<li>` tag, hoping to get those fired before the CSS "display:none" to no avail.

Googled for "How to prevent CSS being fired before HTML click", "Browser event processing order" "Browser code processing order", and many variations with no success.

I would not mind including a JS script, which sadly would debunk the pure CSS solution, which if workable is quite lean. Certainly probably all mobiles can run JS.

I will appreciate any help to resolve this issue.